# Fully residual free groups and surface groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $S$ be a surface group of genus $g > 1$  with presentation 
$$
S := \langle y_1, \ldots, y_g, z_1, \ldots, z_g : [y_1, z_1] \ldots [y_g,z_g] \rangle
$$

Is it true that, given a finite subset $X \subset S$ there exists a surjective group homomorphism $\phi: S \to F_n$ from $S$ onto a free group $F_n$ of rank $n > 1$ such that $\phi(x) \neq 1$ for all $x \in X$?

Comment: Yes, it's a result of G. Baumslag (1962). See e.g. Section 3.2 in Champetier-Guirardel https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401042

Comment: Yves, it takes exactly the same amount of time to post this comment as an answer. Then it could be accepted and the case closed. This way the question remains unanswered and will reappear.